# strip and replace a text string with a regular expression in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to strip and replace a text string in the most elegant way possible:

With the solution I have `/element\s*\{"([^"]+)"\}\s*{text\s*{\s*}\s*({[^}]*})/`

```
text.replaceAll("element\\s*\\{\"([^\"]+)\"}\\s*\\{text\\s*\\{\\s*}\\s*(\\{[^}]*})", "<$1> $2"));
```

Used on the text below:

```
element {"item"} {text { } {$i/child::itemno} text { } {$i/child::description} text { } element {"high_bid"} {{max($b/child::bid)}} text { }}
```

GIVES:

```
<item> {$i/child::itemno} text { } {$i/child::description} text { } element {"high_bid"} {{max($b/child::bid)}} text { }}
```

When I'm trying to achieve:

```
<item>{$i/child::itemno}{$i/child::description}<high_bid>{fn:max($b/child::bid)}</high_bid></item>
```

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing, the problem is that the regex only matches once.

Your regex is looking for element{"tag"} {text { } {text_here}

This only occurs once in your input:

```
element {"item"} {text { } {$i/child::itemno}
```

Nothing else matches:

```
text { } element {"high_bid"} {   => NO MATCH, text without element before it

element {"high_bid"} {{max($b/child::bid)}} text { }   => NO MATCH, text after braces
```

So either your input is bad, or you need something better than a one-shot regex.

That being said, I don't think a regex will work here.  You could remove all of the "text { }" elements, which seem to do nothing:

```
text.replaceAll("text\\s*\\{\\s*}", ""));
```

Which gives you:

```
element {"item"} { {$i/child::itemno}  {$i/child::description}  element {"high_bid"} {{max($b/child::bid)}} }
```

But the problem here is that you have nesting.  If you are simply matching on braces, how do you know how far to match?  You need your regex to comprehend how many opening braces you have, and find the correct closing brace.  This is not really doable with regular expressions.  You need a function that parses the string counting opening braces and subtracting closing braces.  When you get a count of zero, you found a set...  Of course, this is not regular expressions.

Comment: I think on the contrary, I need it to be more greedy. It only removes the first element and the first text instances.

Comment: Quite the opposite in fact.  See my clarification in the answer.  It only LOOKS like it did not replace the latter occurrences because they were slurped into the first text.  After that, no more replacements occur because replacements do not occur on replaced text.

Comment: Can I ask what was the point of telling me to add '?' 
My aim is to scan the entire string for any instance of either group

Comment: I was actually wrong.  I thought the regex was being greedy, but your [^\}] took care of that.  \{.*?\} is basically the same thing.  The real problem is that you only match once.  Where is this data coming from?  Do you have a description of the format?

Comment: It seems as if the "text { }" elements are meaningless.  Strip them out and then do a while loop on the rest.  I will put that in my answer.

Comment: My input comes from an XML engine which appends these tags. I think you are right, I cannot guarantee the order "element", "text". However I didn't think that mattered and if it found "text" without element it would still work.
I therefore need something better.

Comment: Thanks ror your help, I will have a stab at writing a brace recognition method